# Как сохраняется дата рождения пользователя в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня вот стоят combobox - две(день, месяц) и текстовое поле(год). Хочу эти данные занести в БД. Вопрос: Как вообще они ставятся? Создать три отдельных поле для них и по одному вносить туда данные или есть более простой метод?

Answer (score 4):

К примеру,

```
$day = isset($_POST['day']) ? (int)$_POST['day'] : 0;
$month = isset($_POST['month']) ? (int)$_POST['month'] : 0;
$year = isset($_POST['year']) ? (int)$_POST['year'] : 0;

/**
 * Если в UNIX формате (TIMESTAMP)
 * 
 * тогда в БД дата хранится в целочисленном типе (integer)
 */ 
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

/**
 * Если в формате DATE
 */
$date = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

Далее добавляем в БД.

P.S. Хранить необходимо в одном поле, ибо удобне производить сортировку, а в случае если вы используете нативные дата-типы MySQL (DATE, DATETIME...), то это даёт возможность производить различные операции с датой непосредственно в запросе.

Comment: Тогда если я возьму третий случай и напишу его туда. То при вызове из БД данных, он выведется в формате y-m-d, так?

Comment: @navi1893 Какой третий?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал хранить дату рождения так как вам удобней в вашей ситуации.
Как по мне то лучше всего тип **DATE**, но не стоит забывать, что в **MySQL** еще много типов данных, которые могут вам подойти. Я встречал как люди хранят данные даты в типе INT.

**TIMESTAMP** — тип данных для хранения даты и времени. Данные хранятся в виде количества секунд, прошедших с начала «эпохи Юникса». Диапазон значений: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 — 2038-12-31 00:00:00. Занимает 4 байта.

**YEAR** — тип данных для хранения года. Диапазон значений: 1901 — 2155. Занимает 1 байт.

**DATE** — тип данных для хранения даты. Диапазон значений: 1000-01-01 — 9999-12-31. Занимает 3 байта.

**TIME** — тип данных для хранения времени. Диапазон значений: −828:59:59 — 828:59:59. Занимает 3 байта.

**DATETIME** — тип данных для хранения даты и времени. Диапазон значений: 1000-01-01 00:00:00 — 9999-12-31 00:00:00. Занимает 8 байт.

Answer (score 1):

Как хочешь так и сохраняй, хоть в отдельные поля, хоть в одно... Лучше в одном хранить. При получении дат от пользователя собирай их в одну строку... При выводе можно их форматировать либо так же разбивать на части... Тут зависит от того что тебе именно надо.